# Не проходит регистрация в FireBase

Tags: java, android, firebase

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_email_password);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null){

            }
            else {

            }
        }
    };
    ETemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    ETpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);

    findViewById(R.id.bt_sign_in).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.bt_registration).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.bt_sign_in){
        signin("us1@gmail.com","12345678");
        //signin(ETemail.getText().toString(), ETpassword.getText().toString());
    }
    else if (view.getId() == R.id.bt_registration){
        registration("us1@gmail.com","12345678");
        //registration(ETemail.getText().toString(), ETpassword.getText().toString());
    }
}

public void registration (String email, String password){
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this,"Регистрация успешна",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this,"Регистрация провалена",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Связь с Firebase:

Connect your app to Firebase: connected

Add Firebase Authentication...: Dependencies set up correctly

При попытке регистрации следующие ошибки:

```
06-15 10:32:28.381 11335-11335/com.example.tug.cloudtasks E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tug.cloudtasks, PID: 11335
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zzb(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzdf)' on a null object reference
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtp.zzb(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtw.zza(Unknown Source:19)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source:15)
    at com.example.tug.cloudtasks.EmailPasswordActivity.registration(EmailPasswordActivity.java:75)
    at com.example.tug.cloudtasks.EmailPasswordActivity.onClick(EmailPasswordActivity.java:55)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Концептуально код у вас верный. Возможно вы в какие-то ограничения попали. Например на сложность и/или длину пароля. Попробуйте более сложный и длинный пароль использовать.

Comment: Я пробовал, но если бы проблема была в этом, приложение бы не "падало" совсем. Пришел бы ответ какой нибудь.

Comment: Я читал, что null может именно в таком случае приходить. Попробуйте ещё версии библиотек на разные поменять и добавьте их в вопрос. Ещё можно настройки какие-то добавить (настройки доступа в БД например).

Comment: А где `mAuthListener` используется? Может у вас значение `mAuth` устаревает, а новое вы не запоминаете.

Comment: Have you checked the project_id in your Android app google-services.json file is the same as the Firebase project for which you enabled Google Sign In Authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, я смогу вам помочь. Регистрацию я делал в трех или четырех проектах, используя следующий код на Kotlin:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email!!, password).addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        onAuthSuccess(task.result.user.uid)
    } else {
        showIOSDialog(false)
        Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity, getString(R.string.registration_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

В поля *email и password* вставляете то, что ввел пользователь. В настройках firebase вы должны включить регистрацию по email и паролю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Удачи!

**Дополнение № 1**
Забыл привести gradle настройки) Я использую последние версии на текущий момент, вы можете удалить не используемые библиотеки:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.kelvinapps:rxfirebase:0.0.16'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
```

Comment: Для начала мне нужна просто регистрация с авторизацией implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1", но с этой версией (16.0.1) возникает ошибка конфликт версий и я не могу понять в чем конфликт, как это найти.

Comment: вы подключили весь список библиотек?

Comment: да, сначала весь список, потом по одной удалял, оставил в результате firebase-auth:16.0.1 и с этой не стало работать. Не компилируется. Только если возвращаю версию 9.0.0, с ней компилируется, но падает.

Comment: насколько я помню, gms обязательны. Нельзя только 1 оставить

Comment: я пробовал разные варианты, но пока ничего не получилось. Скорее всего конфликт разных версий, но я не понимаю как это решить. Можете поделиться каким нибудь работающим проектом под AndroidStudio где есть хотя бы регистрация с авторизацией? Или попробовать запустить проект, который я указал в вопросе.

Comment: пришлите ссылку на git репозиторий вашего проекта (Zhore-chebotarev@mail.ru), я посмотрю что можно сделать

Comment: а, да, я могу скинуть вам ссылку на свой проект, учебный. Но пока я его подготавливаю к публикации. Вам придется подождать пару дней

Comment: Да, спасибо, я подожду. А ссылку на git скинуть не могу, т.к. я им не пользуюсь.

Comment: Наконец-то закончил то, что должен был закончить. Залил проект https://github.com/georrge1994/Phoenix . Единственное, ключи для firebase я не выкладывал (по понятным причинам). Но авторизация работает, уверяю вас. Ссылку на play market добавлю как только проект опубликуется.